# Creating binaries in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, binaries

I am using https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket for TCP and UDP connections. This library does not have Cocoapods support.

Is there a way to create a binary, if so how can I create a binary and use it in my app, without including the source code?

I want to build this binary for iOS SDK 9 and above.

Comment: Then simply drag and drop this into the project and try to run it .

Comment: I don't want to have the source code for this in my app. I want to build a binary from this code and use it.

Comment: May be this will point you out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial